# Format Date Time Exception in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have built a SSRS report which combines two int columns of data (i.e.: 6 & 2017) to form a valid month and year result in a column of the SSRS report (i.e.: June 2017) using the following statement: `Format(CDate(Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value & "/" & Fields!YearEarned.Value)`

That works as desired, however some of the int values for the month have a value of 13 which is supposed to represent all months of the year so that the required format for these values in the report is such as "All 2017".  I thought an IIF statement such as the following would specify the necessary formating for the exclusion, however the rows with a month value of 13 simply display #error.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
=iif(Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value < 13, Format(CDate(Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value & "/" & Fields!YearEarned.Value), "MMM yyyy"), "All " & Fields!YearEarned.Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in expression is `CDate()` when the `13` occurs. As per the design in SSRS,  `IIF` evaluates `TRUE` and `FALSE` both and in your case when the 13 is selected as `MonthEarnedId` then `CDate()` tries to convert `13/2017` in `MMM yyyy` format which is invalid and throws `#Error`.

I would suggest you to convert the `int` into `month names` in your SQL query and bring the data to just concatenate in SSRS but if you strictly have to do it in SSRS then below is the expression you have to put in.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=1,"Jan"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=2,"Feb"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=3,"Mar"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=4,"Apr"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=5,"May"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=6,"Jun"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=7,"Jul"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=8,"Aug"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=9,"Sep"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=10,"Oct"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=11,"Nov"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=12,"Dec"
,Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value=13,"All"
) & " " & CStr(Fields!YearEarned.Value.Value)
```

Comment: The visibility code you provided is a working solution, however it was very inefficient when running the report.  As a result I took your advice and decided to format the date into a field within my SQL query i.e.: CASE WHEN MonthEarnedId < 13 Then FORMAT(CAST(CONCAT(MonthEarnedId, '/1/', YearEarned) as datetime), 'MMM yyyy') ELSE 'All ' + YearEarned END as MonthEarned

Answer (score 0):

You are casting that field type to a date variant to apply formatting in doing so, you are also changing the data type of the column from string to datetime. The error occurs when the renderer attempts to cast the string value "All 2017" into a corresponding date time. To get around this you need to cast it back to a string subtype using `CStr()` or some other way.

```
=iif(Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value < 13, CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!MonthEarnedId.Value & "/" & Fields!YearEarned.Value), "MMM yyyy")), "All " & Fields!YearEarned.Value)
```